# MySQL Workbench Data Export Select Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am using the Data Export functionality to create a dump of a database in MySQL Workbench. Once I select the database, I want to select a subset of the tables on the right side in the screenshot. However, the list of tables is not displayed. How do I make a single-file dump of a subset of tables of a database?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on one row and you see the tables

[image: Workbench Data export]

Answer (score 0):

It may sound dumb from me, but have you tried to click on the database choosen, not just check it.
Try to click the name of the database.